# Why is artist Heinrich Kley's death date unknown?

Tags: art, death, date

Wikipedia and other information about artist [Heinrich Kley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Kley) tell about his art but not tell why his death date is unknown.

From English Wikipedia:

'The date of Kley's death is uncertain. Rumors initially suggested his demise in the early 1940s. It is also suggested that Kley died on August 2, 1945. Some sources mention the time of death on February 8, 1952.'

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Interestingly enough,  just this week we watched a video [The Man Who Inspired Disney](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjlUdU7CsuE) going over an original sketchbook from this artist.

Answer (score 6):

It is known. Just the English Wikipedia does not mention it. The German one does:

[Shortly before the end of the war, February 8 1945, in Nymphenburger  hospital in Munich.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Kley)

Confirmed by a more reliable source, like

— Stolberg-Wernigerode, Otto zu: Neue deutsche Biographie, Bd.: 12, Kleinhans - Kreling, [Schriftleitung Hauptschriftl. Fritz Wagner ... Genealog. Beratung Friedrich Wilhelm Euler], Berlin, 1980. ([link](https://daten.digitale-sammlungen.de/0001/bsb00016329/images/index.html?seite=75))